# Having trouble compiling Medusa

Tags: windows, cmake, disassembly, building

I've found a very interesting program called Medusa disassembler:
https://github.com/wisk/medusa

However I'm having trouble building it under Windows. I followed the compilation instructions but the it said it can't find the boost libraries. The instructions say I should define "BOOST_LIBRARYDIR" but I don't know how to do this.

Is it an environmental variable or something related to CMake? How do I go about defining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure you have [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) installed on your PC.

After, to "define BOOST_LIBRARYDIR" means to add it as an environment variable. If you are on Windows, go to "System Properties" and open tab "Advanced". There you will find a button "Environment Variables...". For "System variables" add a new variable with the name BOOST_LIBRARYDIR and set the path where your Boost is installed.

Or, if you use Linux command line, you can provide the [path as an argument](https://github.com/wisk/medusa#compilation): `cmake -DBOOST_ROOT:PATH=<path to the boost directory>`